# Does a Fighter's Action Surge stack with the Haste action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fighter

A fighter, once per rest, can use Action Surge to gain an additional action on his turn.

The target of a Haste spell also gains an additional action on his turns (until the spell ends).

If a fighter is Hasted by a fellow mage and then uses his Action Surge, does he gain two additional actions on his turn (for a total of 3 actions, plus the eventual bonus action & reaction) ?

Answer (score 25):

### Does it stack?

Yes. They each add one action. *Haste* has restrictions on how that action may be used, though *Action Surge* does not.

### Do they *multiply*?

Neither *[Haste](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste)* nor *[Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#ActionSurge)* says "doubles your actions" or anything to that effect, they both grant an *additional* action - it's additive, not multiplicative.

Comment: In other words, a creature under the influence of _Haste_ "gains an additional action on each of its **turns**". Since _Action Surge_ doesn't grant a _turn_, but an _action_,  it wouldn't trigger an additional action from the spell.

Comment: Relatedly, abilities that *do* give you an extra turn, like the Thief's Reflexes ability, *would* multiply the actions gained.  So a hasted 17th level thief/ 2nd level fighter with an extra use of action surge from a magic item, for example, could take 6 actions in the first round of a combat.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer That's not multiplicative. Sure, *Thief’s Reflexes* gets two turns during the first round, but each turn is resolved independently and on different initiative counts, no less. Plus... I'm unaware of any item that grants extra Action Surges. It's a stretch to call any of this multiplicative.

Comment: Agreed that the extra magic item is a red herring, but I do agree with his basic premise that a *Hasted* character with *Thief's Reflexes* would get the haste extra action on both his turns, and with *Action Surge* as in the example, could start with 5 actions (and 2 bonus actions, and 4 times movement) on his first turn.  The *Action Surge* only gives an extra action, not an extra turn, so the *Haste* action would not give an extra action for that.